# Mysql query inside radians function not working. Why?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, radians

This works:

```
SELECT
    (
        radians(
            44.43763930
        )
    )
```

This doesn't:

```
SELECT
    (
        radians(
            SELECT
                latitude
            FROM
                coords
            WHERE
                coord_id = '1234'
        )
    )
```

I don't get it. Where is the problem ?

I try to cast the query result into decimal, but stil doesn't work.

Comment: Define *doesn't work*. Are you getting an error? Wrong results?

Comment: I get a query error.

Comment: What result does your subquery yield?  And is it an `int` ?

Comment: you have to store the query in a variable before you can you it for further comutation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the subquery does return one row (not more), this works:

```
SELECT radians( (SELECT latitude FROM coords WHERE coord_id = 1234) )
```

The key is that the subquery needs to be surrounded with parentheses, so the database can understand it as a scalar subquery - that is, a query that returns one column and at most one row.

Note, on the other hand, that the parentheses *around* `radians()` are unnecessary - in both queries.

If the subquery returns more than one row, the query fails at runtime. In that case, you might want to switch to the more conventional phrasing:

```
SELECT radians(latitude) FROM coords WHERE coord_id = 1234
```

Note that I removed the single quotes around the literal value given to `coord_id`; it *looks like* a number, so it should be treated as such (if the column is of a string-like datatype, you can revert that change).

Comment: Ok. Seems that you are right. The problem was the parentheses. I don't really understand why because in radians function is only the query, nothing else. And yes. the query returns only one result. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @andrei - GMB tried to explain. If you want to pass a value from one query to another scope or context, it needs to be wrapped in brackets. Such as; `SELECT * FROM x WHERE y = (SELECT MAX(y) FROM x)` *(such that `y = 1` works without brackets, but `y = SELECT MAX(y) FROM x`, without brackets, does Not work)*.  Then, the function `RADIANS()` also needs its own brackets to mark the position of the parameter. As you're using the result of a sub-query as a parameter in to a function, both pairs of brackets are Required.

Answer (score 0):

You need extra parentheses for the subquery.  However, it is more natural to just move the function call *into* the subquery:

```
SELECT (SELECT RADIANS(latitude)
        FROM coords
        WHERE coord_id = '1234'
       )
```

Of course, it is unclear why you are using a subquery here at all, but that is a different matter.